# List-Unsubscribe-Post: List-Unsubscribe=One-Click Spring boot with AWS SES

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am using AWS SES to send newsletter. I am using spring boot for AWS SES application.  I am trying to implement one-click unsubscribe.
List-Unsubscribe-Post is not working.  I am using like this

List-Unsubscribe-Post: List-Unsubscribe=One-Click
List-Unsubscribe: https://localhost:8080/unsubscribe/example?list=name&email=email

I have tested my POST api by creating form in email and send request. It’s work with my api and unsubscribe from my database.

If i use List-Unsubscribe: https://localhost:8080/unsubscribe/example?list=name&email=email

also work.

List-Unsubscribe-Post:

Only unsubscribe header with one click does not work. When i click on unsubscribe header in gmail, modal open ask to click unsubscribe. When i click get message you are unsubscribe from the email. But POST api has no interaction.

List-Unsubscribe:

Works fine with GET request and unsubscribe in database

String unsubscribeUrl = mailMessage.getUnsubscribeUrl();

if (unsubscribeUrl != null)

builder.withHeader("List-Unsubscribe-Post", "List
Unsubscribe=One-Click");

builder.withHeader("List-Unsubscribe", "<" + unsubscribeUrl + ">");

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow, it would be beneficial to perhaps see some code that you've written specifically. In this case it could mean that your application isn't recognising the path, this can be because your code has marked the endpoint as being GET while your posting or vice versa. Have you check your access logs, perhaps this is already telling

Comment: Thanks Jan.  I have tested same POST api in gmail, That's work fine and unsubscribe in database. But when i use List-Unsubscribe-Post: List-Unsubscribe=One-Click in gmail, it does not work

Comment: POST api is working fine. It's issue in gmail one-click unsubscribe

Comment: I have gone through lot of posts, but cloud not find the solution.

Comment: https://certified-senders.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/CSA_one-click_list-unsubscribe.pdf

Comment: Do you have the request that is being sent including the headers? This would give us some more to go with to help figure out what's not working

Comment: gmail will post like this

Comment: POST /unsubscribe.html?opaque=123456789 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 26
List-Unsubscribe=One-Click

Comment: With my POST api on postman i am testing with raw